# How to deploy Flask app with Supervisor/Nginx/Gunicorn on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on an Ubuntu server. I referenced [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html?highlight=flask), [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/) and [this](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) and found a lot of similar questions on SO, but I still can't figure it out.

I can run it manually from the source directory by doing `uwsgi siti_uwsgi.ini` and navigating to `http://server_IP_address:8080/`. But when I try `uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file views.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2` and navigate to `http://server_IP_address:3031`, I get nothing.

If I go to `siti.company.loc` (the DNS name I set up), there is a standard Nginx 502 error page.

When I try to restart the supervisor process, it dies with a FATAL error:

> can't find command "gunicorn"

What am I doing wrong? Let me know if I need to provide more info or background.

---

/webapps/patch/src/views.py (Flask app):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {'origins': '*'}})

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello'

@app.route('/site:<site>/date:<int:day>-<month>-<int:year>')
def application(site, month, day, year):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Recompile date from URL. todo: better way
        dte = str(day) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(
        print('about to run')
        results = run_SITI(site, dte)
        return results

def run_SITI(site, dte):
    print('running SITI')
    return render_template('results.html', site=site, dte=dte, results=None)  # todo: Show results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

/webapps/patch/siti_wsgi.ini (uWSGI ini):

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8008
chdir = /webapps/patch/src
wsgi-file = views.py
processes = 2
threads = 2
callable = app
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/siti (Nginx config):

```
upstream flask_siti {
        server 127.0.0.1:8008 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name siti.company.loc;
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/siti/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/siti/error.log;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /static {
                alias /webapps/patch/static;
        }
        location /media {
                alias /webapps/patch/media;
        }
        location / {
                # checks for static file, if not found proxy to the app
                try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://flask_siti;
        }
}
```

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/siti.conf (Supervisor config):

```
[program:webapp_siti]
command=gunicorn -b views:app
directory=/webapps/patch/src
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

/var/log/nginx/siti/error.log (Nginx error log):

```
2016/08/30 11:44:42 [error] 25524#0: *73 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, $
2016/08/30 11:44:42 [error] 25524#0: *73 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, $
2016/08/30 11:44:42 [error] 25524#0: *73 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.1.2.195, serve$
```

Comment: you are using the `http` setting in the uwsgi conf, which is different. Just specify a port

Comment: You have typo in supervisord conf: `directory=/webapps/batch` instead of `directory=/webapps/patch`

Comment: @reptilicus I tried as a socket (`uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file views.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2`), but `http:\\server_ip_address:3031` returns nothing

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup fixed, but that's not the issue - happened during copy-pasting the question

Comment: And next typo in nginx config: `server 127.0.0.1:8008 fail_timeout=0;` instead of `server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;`

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup OK, that one was real. I made the change, but same error (edited post)

Comment: You missed a closing bracket `}` in nginx `upstream` config

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup fixed - updated post

Comment: There are some really good boiler plate examples of this setup on github, I recommend just searching for them.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? If yes, where is located?

Comment: Yes - /webapps/patch/venv

Comment: Yes, when you specify a port without the `http` setting, you need to have nginx in front of it. Just specify a port, and point nginx at that port for the upstream and it should work. And yes, need to specify the location of the virtualenv as well

Comment: the `http` setting makes uwsgi act like a full webserver, and nginx expects a wsgi protocol so thats why its freaking out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get it working with the following changes:

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/siti.conf (Supervisor config):

```
[program:webapp_siti]
command=/webapps/patch/venv/bin/gunicorn -b :8118 views:app  # didn't use uwsgi.ini after all
directory=/webapps/patch/src
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/siti (Nginx config):

```
upstream flask_siti {
        server 127.0.0.1:8118 fail_timeout=0;  # changed ports because 8008 was already in use by something else
}
# snip ...
```

Turns out I had set up uWSGI to listen on port 8008. I also had an extra file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled called `siti.save` that was preventing Nginx from reloading. I deleted it, reloaded/restarted Nginx, restarted Supervisor, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have errors in `nginx` config:

Instead of:

```
upstream flask_siti {
        server 127.0.0.1:8008 fail_timeout=0;

server {
   ...
```

try:

```
upstream flask_siti {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
   ...
```

You must "activate" virtualenv in `supervisor` config. To do this, add following line to Your `supervisor` config:

```
environment=PATH="/webapps/patch/venv/bin",VIRTUAL_ENV="/webapps/patch/venv",PYTHONPATH="/webapps/patch/venv/lib/python:/webapps/patch/venv/lib/python/site-packages"
```

Comment: Thanks - that was a real typo, and earlier today I remember getting an error  about that. Doesn't fix it for me, though (see edits)

Comment: I'll try it.. just crashed supervisor when I tried to restart the service (I have the magic touch today!). Going to leave it for tonight and will revisit in the morning. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, got supervisor working - unfortunately still dies with same `can't find command 'gunicorn'` error. Gunicorn is installed in my venv, so not sure why, but this helps... will pick up again tomorrow

Comment: Yes it is. Solved a different way. Thanks for all your help!